# QTextCodec subclass - how to register my codec

Tags: qt, encoding, plugins, character-encoding, codec

I need to create my own codec, i.e. subclass of `QTextCodec`. And I'd like to use it via `QTextCodec::codecForName("myname");`
However, just subclass is not enough. `QTextCodec::availableCodecs()` does not contain my codec name.

QTextCodec documentation does not cover the area of proper registration of a custom codec:

> Creating Your Own Codec Class
>
> Support for new text encodings can be
> added to Qt by creating QTextCodec
> subclasses.
>
> The pure virtual functions describe
> the encoder to the system and the
> coder is used as required in the
> different text file formats supported
> by QTextStream, and under X11, for the
> locale-specific character input and
> output.
>
> To add support for another encoding to
> Qt, make a subclass of QTextCodec and
> implement the functions listed in the
> table below.
> name()
> aliases()
> mibEnum()
> convertToUnicode()
> convertFromUnicode()
>
> You may find it more convenient to
> make your codec class available as a
> plugin; see How to Create Qt Plugins
> for details.

So, I've tried to dig a little into plugins' direction. But I don't want to have a separate project with plugin. Is it possible to declare plugin within the same project?

Or is there a direct way to register my codec into QTextCodec? This is preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to qtextcodex.cpp any new codec is added to the collection of registered codecs (*static QList *all*) by its own constructor. So creating an instance of your codec class should do the trick; code below worked fine for me:

```
QMyCodec myCodec;

foreach (QByteArray codecName,  QTextCodec::availableCodecs())
{
    QString codecNameStr(codecName);
    qDebug() << codecNameStr;
}

QTextCodec* codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("MyNewCodec");
if (codec)
{
    qDebug() << "found ";
    qDebug() << codec->name() << '\n';
}
```

QTextCodec::availableCodecs returned:

> "MyNewCodec"
>   "System"
>   "roman8" 
>   "hp-roman8"
>   "csHPRoman8" ...

QTextCodec::codecForName returned a pointer to my codec class

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Thanks, you're right! My codec's constructor didn't call inherited QTextCodec's constructor. That is why my codec wasn't registered. I should have taken a look at Qt sources.

Comment: @serge_gubenko: I don't know if the spec has changed or this was missed when you wrote this answer, but QTextCodecs must be created on the heap and never deleted explicitly. This can be seen on the QTextCodec::~QTextCodec implementation of qtextcodec.cpp in my Qt 4.8.3 source code, line 974. `QTextCodec should always be constructed on the heap (i.e. with \c
    new). Qt takes ownership and will delete it when the application
    terminates.`

Comment: @Kivin you're right: not using new leads to a delete call on a non-pointer when exiting the application