# How can I convert QByteArray to string in Qt 5.3?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qbytearray

I am using some functions to convert `QVector's` to `QByteArray's`, for example:

```
QByteArray Serialize::serialize(QVector<double> data)
{
    QByteArray byteArray;
    QDataStream out(&byteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out << data;
    return byteArray;
}

void Serialize::deserialize(QByteArray byteArray, QVector<double> *data)
{
    QDataStream in(&byteArray, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    in >> *data;
}
```

Now, that I have the `QByteArray` I need to put it in a text file, how can I convert it to `QString`?

I already tried the simplest way:

```
QString myString(data); // data - QByteArray
```

But `myString` is always empty.

I also found the `toStdString()` function in the documentation, but it was introduced only in **Qt 5.4**.

I'm using **Qt 5.3**.

Follows a complete example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QDebug>
#include <QVector>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDataStream>

QByteArray serialize(QVector<double> data)
{
    QByteArray byteArray;
    QDataStream out(&byteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out << data;
    return byteArray;
}

void deserialize(QByteArray byteArray, QVector<double> *data)
{
    QDataStream in(&byteArray, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    in >> *data;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QVector<double> data;
    data << 1.1 << 2.2 << 3.3 << 4.4 << 5.5 << 6.6 << 7.7 << 8.8 << 9.9;

    QByteArray byteArray = serialize(data);
    QVector<double> dataConverted;
    deserialize(byteArray, &dataConverted);

    qDebug() << "Data:";
    qDebug() << data;
    qDebug() << "ByteArray:";
    QString test(byteArray);
    qDebug() << test;
    qDebug() << "Data Converted:";
    qDebug() << dataConverted;

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Note**: The general objective of this is to generate a **SQL** file with all content from the **SQLite** database. My double vector is converted to `QByteArray` and stored as **BLOB** into the database (using the serialize function). When I need to load it from the database I use the deserialize function to convert to a double vector again. Now I need to generate the **SQL** file with the data in the **BLOB** format, then I can directly import it into another database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a byte array is type-agnostic data type, it simply represents a collection of individual bytes in memory. In your example code you are creating the byte array from a vector of doubles, and then converting back to another vector of doubles. No problem.

However when you pass the byte array into the QString constructor, the QString is trying to interpret the byte array as data that represents a string, for example an array of ASCII character codes.

Some string classes might let you do this, and create an instance filled with garbage, however QString appears to be doing some basic error checking and helping you out by giving you an empty string.

As for some code to print out the contents of a byte array of doubles, the deserialize method you've provided is not too bad an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the complete explanation. Now I understood the problem, but I still don't know how can I print it. Do you know how can I print the byte array? I need to generate a **SQL** file with the **BLOB** content (generated by a `QByteArray`) from the database.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but could you not just loop over the vector, printing out each element to a string? Very basic example:

`QString printVector(QVector<double>* vector)
{
    QString output;

    for (int index = 0; index < vector->length(); index++)
    {
        output += QString::number(vector->at(index)) + ", ";
    }

    return output;
}`

Comment: Actually, I can't because it will just return the double vector as a **QString** (e.g. "1.2,123.2,42.1"). I need to print it as a byte array in the **SQL** file because I will need to import it to another database. E.g.: "`INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(14, "name", here_is_my_blob_type_saved_as_qbytearray);`". **Note**: I'm using **SQLite**.

Comment: Sorry Kelvin, I'm not currently in a position to install SQLite to try this. My best guess is you'll need to find out how you can represent a byte array / blob as a string in the SQL file, possibly using hex or base64. Have a look at QByteArray::toHex(). Good luck

Comment: Thanks @Benp44. Yes, I can do this, but then I need to create a function to read it and convert to `QByteArray` again, and this is not my goal. I gave up on trying to create the **SQL** file and now I am exporting a copy of the database (.DB file) and then I can import it by reading all the content from this DB file and copying to my current database file. Off course this is not the answer for my question, but it solved my major problem.

Comment: **Note**: one reason that I gave up on trying to create the SQL file is the file size. My database has 171 mb, but when I tried to generate the SQL file on another software (SQLite Studio) it generated a SQL file of 331 mb.

Comment: Thanks @KelvinSalton :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `QTextCodec` to convert from `QByteArray` to `QString`, here's an example from [official docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html):

```
QByteArray encodedString = "...";
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("KOI8-R");
QString string = codec->toUnicode(encodedString);
```

And to make the example work, you need to convert the doubles to `QString`s during serialization:

```
QByteArray serialize(QVector<double> data)
{
    QByteArray byteArray;
    QDataStream out(&byteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    for (double d : data) {
        out << QString::number(d);
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

If you don't want to convert individual numbers to string, you can also "stringify" the `QByteArray` with `byteArray.toHex()`:

```
qDebug() << "ByteArray:";
QString test(byteArray.toHex());
```

Comment: I tried it but I'm still getting an empty string. `qDebug() << QTextCodec::codecForName("KOI8-R")->toUnicode(byteArray);` **Note**: my QByteArray is "encoded" from a `QVector<double>`. I think your example doesn't work because of that.

Comment: The problem is in your `serialize()` method, you need to use `QString::number()`. I'll change my answer to explain.

Comment: Maybe this may work but I need to use the data as double type, then I will need to convert it every time that I serialize or deserialize the data (**QString** -> **double** or **double** -> **QString**). My data is very large and it may be a problem.

Comment: In this case simply use `byteArray.toHex()`. I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: Now I see that you have updated your question and your intent is quite different. For generating a `BLOB`, you should really create your own `QTextCodec` subclass that outputs correct escape sequences for non-ASCII bytes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984064/qtextcodec-subclass-how-to-register-my-codec.