# PyQt5: subclassing QTextCodec

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm having issues [creating a subclass of QTextCodec](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html#creating-your-own-codec-class) in PyQt5 (specifically 5.9.2, using Python 3.7).

I've created a MWE demonstrating the issue. Running the following code:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtCore import QTextCodec

class MyCodec(QTextCodec):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.inner_codec = QTextCodec.codecForName('UTF-8')

    def name(self):
        return b'My' + self.inner_codec.name()

    def aliases(self):
        return [b'My' + alias for alias in self.inner_codec.aliases()]

    def mibEnum(self):
        return self.inner_codec.mibEnum()

    def convertFromUnicode(self, input, number, state):
        return self.inner_codec.convertFromUnicode(input, number, state)

    def convertToUnicode(self, chars, len, state):
        return self.inner_codec.convertToUnicode(chars, len, state)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def main():
        codec = QTextCodec.codecForName('MyUTF-8')
        assert codec is None # MyUTF-8 not found!

        mycodec = MyCodec() # error here
        print(mycodec.fromUnicode('hello world!'))

    main()
```

produces the error

```
TypeError: PyQt5.QtCore.QTextCodec cannot be instantiated or sub-classed
```

QTextCodecs are apparently a special kind of beast, where Qt takes ownership on their creation. According to this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986803/10601881), however, they do need to be instantiated to be registered. A comment on that answer by Jesse Hallam states that in C++ the codec would have to be instantiated with `new`; but Python doesn't really do the whole "stack" and "heap" thing.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to implement a QTextCodec in Python as it needs to be registered in the C++ private API

Comment: That's unfortunate. I do know C++, is there a standard way of doing that/extending that?

Comment: I am seeing if the QTextCodec can be implemented as a plugin and thus not have the need to re-compile Qt and PyQt completely.

Comment: I just asked on the pyqt mailing list, and the maintainer of PyQt [replied](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2020-March/042666.html): «I suspect it's probably laziness on my part. I'll take a look.».